# Count number of post of taxonomy2 in a taxonomy1 template

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

Custom post type: **articolo_rassegna**
Custom Taxonomy 1: **progetto-cliente**
Custom Taxonomy 2: **tipologie_uscita**

In home page I get the number of posts of a specific custom taxonomy with:

```
$args1 = get_term( 2, 'tipologie_uscita' );
$cartaStampataVal=$args1->count;
$cartaStampata = number_format($cartaStampataVal , 0, ',', '.') ;
```

Now I would like to do the same operation in taxonomy template page
At present I get only the number of posts with:

```
$ritagli = get_queried_object();
$countRitagli = $ritagli->count;
$totalePost = number_format($countRitagli , 0, ',', '.') ;
```

but I would like the number of post of the taxonomy2

Answer (score 0):

hope this help you.

```
$args1 = get_term( get_queried_object()->term_id, 'tipologie_uscita' );
$cartaStampataVal=$args1->count;
$cartaStampata = number_format($countRitagli , 0, ',', '.') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with new WP_Query

```
$args1 = new WP_Query( array( 'progetto-cliente' => $progetto_cliente, 'tipologie_uscita' => 'carta-stampata' ) );
$cartaStampataVal = $args1->found_posts;
$cartaStampata = number_format($cartaStampataVal , 0, ',', '.') ;
```

I don't like it, but it works.